# django error NameError: name 'DEBUG' is not defined

Tags: django

i am running my django framework and this error show up , i checked online but did not find any solution

here is the error it show

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 16, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Emacs\.virtualenvs\back-97G-SXVS\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Emacs\.virtualenvs\back-97G-SXVS\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 317, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Emacs\.virtualenvs\back-97G-SXVS\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Emacs\.virtualenvs\back-97G-SXVS\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Emacs\.virtualenvs\back-97G-SXVS\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Emacs\.virtualenvs\back-97G-SXVS\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\_monster\Desktop\skill\djember_cookiecutter\djember_test\back\settings.py", line 161, in <module>
    if DEBUG:
NameError: name 'DEBUG' is not defined
```

so anyone have any idea ?

Comment: Looks like name 'DEBUG' is not defined:) Can you check if `DEBUG` variable defined in your settings.py file? You should have something like this `DEBUG = False` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **settings.py** `DEBUG` variable is missing. Put it in there.

```
DEBUG = True #True for development, False for deployment
```

Answer (score 0):

The traceback indicates you have a statement (`if DEBUG:`) in your project's `settings.py` file on line 161 that calls an undefined variable in your script's namespace.

Typically `DEBUG` is defined in `settings.py`. Perhaps you attempted to use the variable before it was declared? Either that or `DEBUG` isn't defined at all.